# Changing metatag "title"

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, title, meta-tags

I need to change the title of my website, because now the title is "Home".I want to add a "like" button to the website and I want something different instead of "Home" for the title. I tried changing the meta tag for "title" but running the url through the facebookb debug tool it says:

> Attempted Frozen Title Change It appears that you are trying to change
>   the property og:title from XX to XY. If so, you are not allowed to for
>   this object because too many actions have been published against it.

How can I change the title? Thank you!
Sorry if my english is full of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to change it. Facebook is basically telling you too many users have the object with the original title connected on Facebook. Changing after too many actions can be seen as an attempt to be misleading.